# Delete all Rows and insert in Oracle can make performance worse?

Tags: oracle

I´m working in a project that I need to make a batch update periodically (every 4 months) from excel files. These excel files doesn´t have keys in theirs rows.

The development of a code that deletes all rows and inserts the whole database again is easier than one that checks in every row and its primary key(that sometimes can be a 5 columns key).

My question is: 
If delete the all the rows of a table and insert it again, if it will cause tablespace fragmentation  and in a future a performce loss.

Thanks in advance

Alexandre

Comment: you'd be better off truncating the table

Comment: A question usually ends with a question mark. What's your question ? Also, I basically understand what your 2 options are, but deleting and reinserting everything is only feasible if there's no link between the data in your table and other tables, cause if there is one, then you will lose it !

Comment: As a third option, or at least a variation of the second, have you considered a [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm)? Truncate and insert may still be preferable; but that does have the disadvantage that `truncate` implicitly commits, so you can have a period where the table is empty to other sessions - which may or may not matter to you.

Comment: Are you doing direct-path inserts?  Or conventional path inserts?  What is your definition of "fragmentation"?  Are you using a vaguely recent version of Oracle with locally managed tablespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can stop all other activity on the database while you re-load the table, the best way of handling it would be

```
truncate table my_table drop storage;
insert ...
```

followed by your inserts. This will effectively wipe out every kind of structure that was on the table rows, and re-build the table. As Alex Poole said, `truncate table` will do a commit as well, so your application won't see the data while it's being rebuilt.

If you can't bring your application down during your updates, you might try

```
delete from table
insert  ...
commit work;
```

in one big transaction (Make sure to turn automatic commit off, depending on what kind of script/language you use to do your inserts). This won't let your clients see any changes until you commit, and makes sure the new rows get inserted in "fresh space", because oracle can't delete the original rows until you commit. This also means that you need double the space on your table for a while, and depending on the size of your data, might fill your redo logs as well.

Both these methods will create less fragmentation than if you alternate between deletes and inserts. (In some cases, there won't be fragmentation at all either way; for example, if you don't have any varchars or other data types with non-constant lengths, every row will take the same amount of space. In this specific scenario, alternating between deletes and inserts might even be better since every deleted row can be re-used at once).

What you should do in any case is, after filling the tables, is to rebuild your index statistics. These are used by the optimizer to choose the order of tables for joins, and if they're wrong, your queries could become *much* slower. In older versions of oracle, you'd use one of

```
analyze index i1 estimate statistics
analyze index i1 compute statistics
```

with the former being faster, the latter being more thorough. In newer versions of oracle, these commands will still work, but there are faster versions in the dbms_package that will work in parallel. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm) for more information, especially the GATHER_*_STATS procedures.

Comment: Thanks Guntram. My application will be offline during the changes. I have some varchars so maybe the first solution would be better. I´ll make some tests then I put the results here. Thanks all you that posted here.